# Unable to perform Graph user search using API Explorer

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search

I'm having an issue getting the graph search to work when I manually use the Graph API Explorer to generate an access token for myself against my application.

I've created an application, set the sandboxed mode to 'off', and then manually granted my user account permissions to my application. To be safe, I included all the permissions available in the graph API explorer before generating the access token.

When I click on my access token, I see that it is still valid, and has all the permissions listed, however, when I perform the following search:

`/search?q=myphonenumber&type=user`

I get an error saying:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

I know the above search code is valid because I was able to get it working a few days ago, I can't seem to figure out what has changed. Am I missing a permission somewhere that prevents me from using my access token to do an API search?

UPDATE: I should also mention that normal `/me` queries work just fine, it seems to be only the search which is disallowed.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when searching for email addresses using the same search term. While researching the problem, I found this bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/453298034751100?browse=search_516534c213df06064266897. So Facebook is aware of the problem but nothing has changed for more than a week now.

Comment: So, what is the solution for this.
App access token is not allowed and page access token is expired after some time.
We can not live out website in this situation.